# Pouchdb, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Cors is enabled and configured correctly

Tags: cors, pouchdb

I am getting the "XMLHttpRequest cannot load DBPATHHERE. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin localhost is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401." error. I've dealt with this before and went over my cors options two dozen times.

```
curl DBPATHHERE/_config/cors
curl DBPATHHERE/_config/httpd/enable_cors
```

Spits out:

```
"{"credentials":"true","origins":"*","methods":"GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE","headers":"accept,     authorization, content-type, origin, referer"}"

"true"
```

Answer (score 0):

For future travellers, I figured out I had the default couchdb version provided by debian apt-get, 1.2, which doesn't support cors. Had to build from source, which was it's own adventure.